# ReactJS: Click on a button to change component on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Say I am rendering a signup component on a page. And I have a button that says submit and login. When I click on the login button I want it to replace the signup component without having to go another page. Just wondering, conceptually how would I implement the onclick handler. Would I need to use react router?

Comment: This is an open ended question but no you wouldn't need to use a router, you can change what renders on the page using JS logic, in this case you could change state and choose what to render when the component re-renders. Or you could send an action to e.g. redux and have the tree render from further up

Comment: @DominicTobias thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a ternary statement to conditionally render components.

Fist declare some sort of variable in state to handle the component switch:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      login: false
   }
}
```

Then in your click handler for your button you would handle the switching of this variable:

```
onClick = event => {
   this.setState({login: !this.state.login})//sets it to opposite of previous value
}
```

Then in your render you would implement the ternary statement

```
render() {
    return(
       this.state.login ? //if login is true
          <SomeComponent
             onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
          />
       : //else
          <AnotherComponent
             onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
          />
    )
}
```

And in both components you would have to have a button:

```
<button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Switch Component</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the react-router-dom Link:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and the button would look something like this:

```
<button component={Link} to="/yourpage">
```

Comment: This will reroute I believe the OP asked to not reroute

Answer (score 0):

Using Router Library is the right way to navigate between components. Since, you do not want to use routing, you can try something like this:

maintain a state variable to check wether the user is logged in, in the parent component where you want to replace the Signup screen with another screen i.e.

```
constructor(props) { /* Parent Component Constructor */
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      isLoggedIn : false
   }
}
```

and the `onLoginClick` in Parent Component method will be:

```
onLoginClick = () => {
 this.setState({ isLoggedIn : true })
}
```

This value will be set to true, when you click on the Login button in the Login Component(Child Component), The onLoginClick method will be passed as props from parent component i.e.

```
<Button onClick={this.props.onLoginClick}>Login</Button>
```

Now use this `isLoggedIn` state variable in the render function of Parent Component like this:

```
render() {
    return(
      {!this.state.isLoggedIn &&
          <LoginComponent
             onClick={this.onLoginClick.bind(this)}
          />
       }
       {this.state.isLoggedIn &&
          <SecondComponent/>
       }
    )
}
```